# Java programs about generics

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Using Generics to count the occurrence of an element in an array of any 
type.

The signature of the count method is given below:

```
public static <T> int count(T[] array, T item)
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Did you submit your question too early by accident?

Comment: that is something you can do with java, is there a question about it?

Comment: Write a java method using Generics to count the occurrence of an element in an array of any 
type. The signature of count method is given below.
public static <T> int count(T[] array, T item) 

Comment: What have you already tried to do? Could you please provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far? Or are you just hoping that someone here will answer your homework?

Comment: I see, you just copied from the homework question without even rewording. Ohhhhh...

Comment: @Asish add atleast a question, don't leave us guessing

Comment: Then tell me the answer..

Comment: Did you try something @Asish?

Answer (score 2):

Using java 8 & Object, no actual need for generics:

```
public static int count(Object[] array, Object item){
    if(item == null){
        return Math.toIntExact(Arrays.asList(array).stream().filter(e -> e == null).count());
    }
    return Math.toIntExact(Arrays.asList(array).stream().filter(e -> item.equals(e)).count());
}
```

Edit : if you really want generics :

```
public static <T> int count(T[] array, T item){
    if(item == null){
        return Math.toIntExact(Arrays.asList(array).stream().filter(e -> e == null).count());
    }
    return Math.toIntExact(Arrays.asList(array).stream().filter(e -> item.equals(e)).count());
}
```

EDIT AGAIN : 
if jdk 8 is too much for you :

```
public static <T> int count(T[] array, T item){
    boolean isNull = item == null;
    int c = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        if(isNull && array[i] == null){
            c++;
        } else if(item.equals(array[i])) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: But how to count the occurrence of an element in an array without built-in function?

Comment: Cf my new edit.

Comment: Thank you.Sir.. But boolean isNull = item == null; I can't understand.. Can you please explain??

Comment: Well, you can't ask a null pointer to perform the .equals() method. So, if the item you want to check is null, the check "item.equals(array[i])" will break. You need to check the null case separately. I just created a boolean equals to "item == null" to avoid checking for null again and again.

Comment: Yeah  I got it.. Thank you..